# Universal location to write a file to, under any version of Windows in any language

Tags: windows, universal

Having to deploy a VBA application on several computers under Windows XP, I needed to automatically create a particular file in an universal place, independent of hard drives, directory structure, even the OS language: the root directory of the C drive, namely C:\

This worked fine ... until these computers started to migrate to Vista or Windows 7, which I discovered don't easily allow writing on the C drive.
What could be an alternate universal writable location that would work under any version of Windows, in any language, for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a Windows API that returns the path to a `SpecialFolder` on the respective machine and use that - well suited are for example

- `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS` (non-user-specific)
- `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA` (non-user-specific)
- `CSIDL_APPDATA` (user-/app-specific)
- `CSIDL_MY_DOCUMENTS` (user-specific)

The Windows API takes care of all that you described - locations above are writeable, work for all Windows versions and not language-dependent.

For VBA source code and samples see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SpecialFolders.aspx

For MSDN references see:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/252652/en-us
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you Yahia for your prompt and assertive answer. I was hoping for a simpler solution, specially after I looked at the VBA code, but I must now accept that it won't be as simple as the C:\  - By the way, my  research led me to something called appdata. Anybody?

Comment: `appdata` is just the name of the location and already part of my answer above... please don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...